# Is it possible to use T4MVC with custom routes defined in global.asax?

Tags: t4mvc

I'd like to be able to use T4MVC with custom routes.
Is this possible and how do I use it?  I've not seen anything generated in the strong helpers to be able to do this.  Since the custom routes are just strings, I don't know if this is even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by custom route you mean 'named routes', then T4MVC indeed doesn't generate anything for them, as that would require parsing your code.

Instead, the simple thing to do is to just define a public constant with the route name, and use that both in the route definition and wherever you need to refer to the named route.